# Karate kata event regarding disqualification

Tags: karate, forms

If disqualified due to not doing bow after completion of kata? Can we defend and apply to qualify?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever a competitor is disqualified due to an unfair ruling, it is the job of that competitor's coach to step in immediately and appeal the ruling. But, the coach must provide a good reason for why the decision should be overturned.

For example, if a competitor is disqualified because he/she forgot to bow at the end of the kata, the coach could step in and appeal on behalf of the competitor by reminding the judges that the rules state the penalty for forgetting to bow should be a half point deduction, not a disqualification. That appeal is valid, and the judges can change their decision based on it.

However, if the coach merely asked the judges to reverse their decision because it's the competitor's first time competing, that probably won't change their ruling. It wouldn't be a valid reason for appealing the decision, in other words.

Disqualifications happen a lot, especially to young and inexperienced competitors. It's upsetting to be disqualified, but it can be a valuable learning experience.

Hope that helps.